# What is the correct way to access __unicode__()?

Tags: django

I have the following class:

```
class Whuffie(models.Model):
    """Holds the amount of whuffie an engineer has earned in each project"""

    engineer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="related_project")
    whuffie = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False
    experience = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    mana = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s (%s)" % (self.engineer.__str__() + self.project.__str__())
```

Am I using **str**() correctly in **unicode**()?

and in my test where I look to see if the record has been created properly am I still OK to call **str**() in that manner, even though it's supposed to be a magic method?

```
def setUp(self):
    """Set up the shared test data."""
    self.w = Whuffie.objects.get(pk=1)

def testWhuffieNameIsProjectAndEngineer(self):
    """
    Tests that the name of the individual whuffie line is "Engineer (Project Name)".
    """

    self.assertTrue(self.w != None)
    self.assertEqual(self.w.__str__(), "Engineer (Test Project)")
```

Elsewhere in Django **str()** is called whenever you reference the object instance itself so I was expecting to be able to test like this:

`self.assertEqual(self.w, "Engineer (Test Project)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `__unicode__()` must return a `unicode`.

```
class Whuffie(models.Model):
      ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s (%s)" % (self.engineer + self.project)
```

Call `unicode()` if you want to access an object's `__unicode__()` method.

Comment: Good spot, I've amended my code.

I've tried calling str() & unicode() and I get errors `AttributeError: 'Whuffie' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: @Stuart str and unicode are built-in Python functions.  You are trying to use them as a Django Model method which they are not.  References: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str, http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unicode

Answer (score 4):

```
self.assertEqual(unicode(self.w), u"Engineer (Test Project)")
```

and

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s (%s)" % (self.engineer, self.project) #unicode will be called automatically
```